# Extend Ubuntu Partition to a Windows Drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk

I'm running out of space on my root(/sda10). I want to merge the drive Ubuntu(/sda8 - 10 GiB) in my root(/sda10).

I don't have any unallocated space so.

1. Should I format the Ubuntu(/sd8) in ext4 format and then resize the /sda10 parition?
2. I read here [[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) ] that GParted has to resize a partition above or below your partition that you need to extend -- which is a bit confusing.

Below is my parition screenshot.

[image: This is my parition screenshot.]

Comment: Your drive is full. Partitions need extra space to function. NTFS needs about 30% free to run really well, at 10% free, you just about cannot run a defrag. Linux partitions also need some extra space, but hides 5% to prevent total crash. But I think gparted shows actual use with 5%.

Comment: I have the extra space in form of Ubuntu (/sd8 ntfs 10gb) drive. I want to merge this drive into my /sda10.

Comment: If **/dev/sd8** doesn't have any data then what I suggest is to format it to **ext4** i,e same partition as **/dev/sda10** and then merge it without loosing any data using **gparted**. Hope you got it what I want to say.